# How to choose a txt file from raw folder, get path and read data?

Tags: java, android

I have a big text file of about 40mbs, I have been looking for a way to read its contents and I found this:

```
File f = new File(String.valueOf(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test)));

try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@ead83c (No such file or directory)
```

The file I am trying to access is in **raw** folder, and its name is **test.txt**

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: did you check following tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-a-txt-file-in-external-storage-with-runtime-permission-in-android

Comment: `openRawResource` already returns an `InputStream`, you don't need to pass through a `File` and a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: may you help with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Resources.openRawResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int)) already gives you an `InputStream`.

```java
final InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    // ...
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Raw resources are packed inside the APK. They're not accessible using a file system path you're used to.

Comment: What us in.close(); ?

Comment: Close the data stream when you're done reading. `is` was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.